# SSH-ing into the VPN server you are connected to

Tags: networking, ssh, mac, vpn, firewall

I have a server running Ubuntu 22.04 that has an Outline VPN service on port 443 (x.x.x.x). I'm trying to SSH into that server (x.x.x.x) while connected to the VPN (x.x.x.x) on Mac. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoRNs.png)

I have tried to SSH into other servers on port 22 while connected to the VPN and it works. For example, when I use telnet to test `test.rebex.net` on port 22 over the VPN, there is this response:

```
Trying 194.108.117.16...
Connected to test.rebex.net.
```

When I SSH to the server while connected to VPN, it hangs. If I try to telnet x.x.x.x on port 22 this happens:

```
Trying x.x.x.x...
telnet: connect to address x.x.x.x: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

However, I can telnet to x.x.x.x on ports 80 and 443. Additionally, I can ssh into the server without the VPN on, signaling that port 22 is not blocked by the server firewall.

Comment: It could be that the firewall is more specific then you think - ie it is looking for the destination IP as well. It could also be that SSH is bound to a specific IP or Interface or conceivably (but unlikely) an MTU issue or reverse path filtering issue.

Comment: It seems this is only an issue when I am on public wifi that blocks port 22. At my private wifi I am able to SSH while connected to VPN. However, on that public wifi that blocks port 22, when I am connected to VPN I can SSH into other devices.